# R - Multivariate K-nearest neighbor outlier detection

Tags: r, outliers, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to implement the algorithm K-nearest neighbor to detect outlier from a multivariate dataset. I don't know how to do it. Could you provide me some example?

Comment: For more idea see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287465004_presentation_of_Centralized_KNN_anomaly_detector_for_WSN
you can follow me and use my works in your bibliography
If you have publications for it you can propose it to me to read and refernce you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1NN outlier detection:

For each object:

1. compute the distance to all other objects
2. find the minimum (for larger k, choose the k smallest distance)
3. store as outlier score

Usually k=1 to k=10 will be enough. See for example:

> **On the Evaluation of Unsupervised Outlier Detection: Measures, Datasets, and an Empirical Study**
>   by G. O. Campos, A. Zimek, J. Sander, R. J. G. B. Campello, B. Micenková, E. Schubert, I. Assent and M. E. Houle
>   Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery 30(4): 891-927, 2016, DOI: 10.1007/s10618-015-0444-8

They did an insane amount of experiments. But on most data sets, kNN with k=1 was one of the best methods of I recall correctly.

Comment: so if two outliers happen to be close to one another, they will never be flagged?

Comment: Not if you use $k=1$. I gave the approach for 1NN only.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thanks for the answer. Could you provide me an example in R for 5 variables?

Comment: No. I don't use R much anymore, it is too slow; you need to rewrite everything in Rcpp (i.e. C++) sooner or later, unfortunately.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, I am implementing the same thing in R. There is another Kth NN method to detect anomalies. It doesn't take average of K neighbors but just the distance from kth neighbour.

Comment: @user603 ,there is no predefined way to select K. According to literature it should be 10-50.

Comment: @ArpitSisodia: I don't use knn much and so maybe that's why I don't understand your comment. Otherwise I'am impressed 'the litterature' has managed to show there are never more than 50 clusters and never less than 10. Could you cite a source for this claim tho?

Comment: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0152173#sec008 go to unsupervised anomaly detection section-> k-nn Global Anomaly detection

Comment: @user603 K is not the number of clusters like K-means. It's number of neighbors to consider for nearness and outlierness.

Comment: @ArpitSisodia: Are you claiming that kmeans with k=50 will always find all the right outliers? Then I can confirm you you are wrong. It's fairly easy to make a counter-example.

Comment: @user603 seems like u r mixing K-means and KNN. ( definition of K is different in both the algo)

Comment: @ArpitSisodia: only in my comment above. You can substitute kmeans in that comment by KNN, my claim stands.

Comment: In my experience k=1 is usually best, except for huge data with many duplicates. You rarely need larger k.

Comment: We're only talking kNN, not k-means which is parameterized *very* differently. I've also linked an extensive evaluation study above, from "Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery". IMHO it is a bit better than the PLOS one.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmnz05clo29wtni/An%20Efficient%20Intrinsic%20Authorship%20Verification%20Scheme%20-%20Based%20on%20Ensemble%20Learning.pdf?dl=0) is a paper that deals with authorship verification, which is a one- class-classification problem and hence, suiteable for outlier detection.

The proposed method in the paper uses an ensemble of nearest neighbour classifiers. It is pretty simple to implement...